# In Photoshop, how to get the histogram and statistics of CIELab values

Tags: photoshop, lab-colorspace

I have a CIELab file that I am looking at with Photoshop. I would like to obtain the m**ean value of the image's L*, a*, and b* values**. However, when I open the Histogram tool and select the individual Lab channels, the displayed mean value is different than then L*a*b* values displayed by the Info tool, which are correct. For example the mean L* value is listed as 251 when it should be 99 based on the Info tool, the a* mean value is listed as 127 when it is should be -1, and the mean b* value is 128 when it should be 0. The listed values might make sense if PS is taking the **mean of the unsigned 8-bit values** which I got from [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/lab2uint16.html), instead of the mean of the L*a*b* values displayed by the Info tool. Is that right? Or, is there a way to convert the incorrect mean L*a*b* value into the correct mean L*a*b* value?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have an image containing Lab values. I want to know the mean Lab value for the image. What Photoshop is displaying as the mean Lab value is wrong, but can I correct it to get the correct mean Lab value? I edited the question to be (hopefully) clearer.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by calculating the mean values? And why are you using Photoshop for this?

Comment: BTW, to get good "info" readings, set the info dialog precision at 32bits for any colorspace. This will show L*a*b* values to fractional precision. Be sure to set zoom factors at multiples of 100% (100, 200, etc). Otherwise Photoshop uses interpolated values which appear to be what it generates for the display and they can be off. I've seen as much as 0.4 variation from actuals.

Comment: mattdm, I wanted to use Photoshop and the mean L*a*b values to help me decode the file, which is in a tricky format that doug refers to in his answer. But it sounds like Photoshop doesn't decode it right!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about photography but rather about decoding technical information from an image file in a non-photographic context.

Comment: The current tagline for Photoshop is _"Create and enhance your photos, images, and designs with Adobe Photoshop CC, the world's best imaging and photo editing software."_ That's it's purpose. You are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @mattdm  Photoshop is used by photographers for all sorts of purposes and it's accreted a huge amount of stuff to deal with the variety of different needs. Some use Lab colorspace as they find separating out color (a* and b*) axis and lightness L*, intuitive. And some use a histogram and averages of L* to standardize high key and low key images. The way Photoshop poorly shows this and clarification of what it provides is of use to those folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop's histogram provides means(averages) for Lightness, a, and b.

They are not normalized but shown in the LAB PCS space used by ICC profiles which go from 0 to 255 in unsigned, 8 bit values.

To convert these to real L*a*b* values, divide the lightness reading by 2.55 to get the actual L*. Subtract 128 from the a and b values to get the true, CIE a* and b* values.

If you are interested, the details of conversion of L*a*b* into the LAB PCS system can be found at www.color.org and is detailed in the specification for ICC profiles.

I don't know for sure but guess that Photoshop's histogram was hard coded for RGB values from 0-255 and they didn't do the work necessary to scale it properly for L*a*b*. They also scale their histogram 0-255 even for 16 bit RGB spaces.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find the Info dialog settings in PS that you mention in your comment? I don't see it in Edit > Preferences, nor in Edit > Color Settings. Am I missing it there? I am using CS6

Comment: I believe Adobe added this after they enhanced Photoshop to include super high dynamic range 32 bit images. It's been in PS CC for quite a while but I'm pretty sure it wasn't available in CS6.